# Contar registros en una tabla

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, asp

Tengo un view donde quiero meter en un viewbag todos los registros que tengo en una tabla, osea... contar cuantos tengo y ya tengo 1 hora buscando pero no he encontrado nada util.

tengo este viewBag pero esta incompleto:

```
ViewBag.Reasignadas = db.SolicitudReasignaciones.Where(x => x.SolicitudReasignacionId).Count();
```

donde "SolicitudReasignacones, es mi tabla.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

¿probaste:

```
db.SolicitudReasignaciones.Count();
```

?